# Homotopy on a cylinder

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Given a cylinder $C := \mathbb{R} \times S^1$, the fundamental group is $\pi_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

My basic question is: Why? I completely fail to see what the set of non-homotopic loops on the cylinder has do with a set of integers? Is there an intuitive or pictorial way to understand this or am I missing something trivial?

Comment: The integer is the number of times a loop winds around the cylinder. (Same as for a circle.)

Comment: Do you know why the fundamental group of $S^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$?